# border image not work in css triangle

Tags: html, css

I have this code for css triangle :

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="triangle"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 100px 500px 0 500px;
    border-color: #009999;
    -webkit-border-image: url('http://kinderhtml.themerex.net/img/bg/texture_2.png');
    /* Safari 3.1-5 */
    -o-border-image: url('http://kinderhtml.themerex.net/img/bg/texture_2.png');
    /* Opera 11-12.1 */
    border-image: url('http://kinderhtml.themerex.net/img/bg/texture_2.png');
}
```

But in action border image not work! how do fix this ?!

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4onnaoa2/4/)

Comment: Did you try a different image ? Your current image is blank

Comment: @Akshay: image worked! this is texture image for repeat. check again.

Comment: The texture image is not clear so you can not see the image. Edit your texture image by Photoshop or other application.[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4onnaoa2/6/)

Comment: @NewCod3r: Your border image is a transparent (or near transparent texture) and unless you have a color to go above/below it you won't see anything and that's why adding a `background` is required. `border-color` wouldn't have any effect here. So, you'd have to change the image (or) add a background like mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: @alirezasafian: if u change black to gray u see my texture: http://jsfiddle.net/4onnaoa2/7/

Comment: @Harry: please see this demo : http://jsfiddle.net/4onnaoa2/7/ triangle not work for me

Comment: What do you mean by triangle not working? It is showing the texture (albeit very light).

Comment: @Harry: i need to show texture to triangle!! can u see triangle ?!

Comment: @NewCod3r: Ok I understand now but I don't think you can create a triangle while using `border-image` (unlike solid borders).

Answer (score 0):

Triangle https://jsfiddle.net/mckyep43/

HTML

```
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

CSS

```
.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 100px 150px 100px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #000000 transparent;
}
```